# Login problems on multisite installation with different domains

Tags: multisite, subdomains, cookies, domain-mapping

I have a subdomain multisite installation in **site.com**, with subsites such as **sub1.site.com**, **sub2.site.com** etc. I needed to transfer one of these sites to an own domain, **sub1.com**.

So I changed the domain value from `sub1.site.com` to `sub1.com` on the network admin panel and at first it seemed to be working. However, I was not able to log in to the admin panel on the transferred site at `sub1.com/wp-login.php`. No error messages, but returned on the same page every time.

I figured this was a cookie problem, and I changed the `COOKIE_DOMAIN` value to `false` in `wp-config.php` and it started working again.

However, later some users using other subdomain sites reported they have had problems logging in, but managed to do so eventually by trying many, many times.

I was wondering if this was a one time problem because of the changed cookie settings, or is this a real problem that I should worry about? Is it OK to leave the `COOKIE_DOMAIN` value to `false`? I did try installing the **MU Domain Mapping** plugin, but didn't manage to set it up right. Can this be done without it?

Comment: This works for me when I set the constant to an empty string.

Comment: I tried that, and now I'm not able to log in at all to sub1.com site, even though I tried to change it back to `false`

Comment: Are all browser cookies deleted?

Comment: Sorry, I was testing a wrong site. So, actually the empty string works equally well as `false`. I'll leave that on, wait and see if there are any problems. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line of code to wp-config.php near your Multisite config settings.

define('COOKIE_DOMAIN',FALSE);

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use

define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );